# Insert data into an Enhanced Rich Text field by QueryString? (SP2010)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to edit a "new item" list form to allow it to fill in values sent as parameters in the querystring. The [standard javascript methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/using-javascript-to-manipulate-a-list-form-field) work fine for most fields, but I'm absolutely stumped trying to insert data into an Enhanced Rich Text field. I know that MS provides a host of methods like `RTE_GetEditorDocument(strBaseElementID)`, but these only appear to work for regular Rich Text fields, not *Enhanced* Rich Text.

The difference seems to be that with the regular Rich Text field, the formatting controls appear inline, while with Enhanced, they appear on the ribbon. With this enhanced version, it doesn't appear that there's anything I can use as a handle to get access to wherever the data is being stored. There isn't a single textarea on the page, nor an iFrame.

There's an `input` control with the attribute `id="ctl00_m_g_f2b81200_9fde_4fc8_9b4e_973579d51926_ff81_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_spSave"`, which looks promising, but setting the value of this doesn't accomplish anything. There's also a `div` with `id="ctl00_m_g_f2b81200_9fde_4fc8_9b4e_973579d51926_ff81_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte"`. Sometimes the div has a `p` control attached to it, and sometimes not, seemingly at random, which also doesn't appear to do anything when I set its value.

**EDIT:** I think I'm most of the way there, but this seems remarkably resistant to editing. From the console, I can get the value to change by running the following:

```
document.getElementById(
  'ctl00_m_g_f2b81200_9fde_4fc8_9b4e_973579d51926_ff81_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte'
  ).getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = 'Test'
```

However, if I try to add that code to my script, it doesn't work -- even if I use that same code verbatim, without any variables. I get the error *"Unable to set value of the property 'innerText': object is null or undefined"*, and after that, entering it from the console fails too, until I refresh the page. **/EDIT**

Does anyone know how to do this? I know I can always ditch the Enhanced Rich Text, and I will if I have to, but I'd love to figure out how to make this work.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you ever resolve this? I am getting The value of the property 'RTE_GetEditorDocument' is null or undefined while trying to use javascript to access SharePoint spellchecker

Comment: No, I eventually just gave up on using the Enhanced Rich Text. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful!